# Optimize a long running hive SQL query - has a join with same table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-tez

The below query takes a lot of time to execute. It is run with tez execution engine.

```
SELECT STG.EMP_TYPE, DEPT, A.TOTAL_COUNT, COUNT(DISTINCT EMP_ID) AS COUNT_DEPT
FROM 
STAGE_SOURCE STG 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
( SELECT EMP_TYPE, COUNT(DISTINCT EMP_ID) AS TOTAL_COUNT 
  FROM STAGE_SOURCE 
  GROUP BY EMP_TYPE 
) A
ON STG.EMP_TYPE = A.EMP_TYPE
GROUP BY STG.EMP_TYPE, DEPT, A.TOTAL_COUNT;
```

Is there any rewrite option or optimization strategy which can improve the query performance?

Comment: Why does it need to be an outer?  Clearly the EMP_TYPE as to be in A.

Comment: changing from outer join to inner join, will it improve performance?

Comment: Can it hurt performance?  The reference to  A.TOTAL_COUNT kills the left anyway.  Clean coding practices tends to lead to efficient code.  You could like try.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend fetching table records only once.

Your inner aggregate computation could be done using a [window function](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.0.2/ds_Hive/language_manual/ptf-window.html).

I believe that this query should give you the same results and you would get rid of `JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    EMP_TYPE,
    DEPT,
    COUNT( DISTINCT EMP_ID ) OVER ( PARTITION BY EMP_TYPE ) AS TOTAL_COUNT,
    COUNT( DISTINCT EMP_ID ) AS COUNT_DEPT
FROM
    STAGE_SOURCE
GROUP BY EMP_TYPE, DEPT
```

Remember that a `GROUP BY` can also take advantage of Indexes.

Here's the link to Apache Hive manual about [Windowing and Analytics Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics)

**#Edit after your comment**

At least in `PostgreSQL` clause `DISTINCT` is applied after window function aggregate computations, leading us to a bit of an exploit which may give you what you need. This way we got rid of `GROUP BY`. See how it works on Postgres: <kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/49a1e/1)</kbd>

Try the below query:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    EMP_TYPE,
    DEPT,
    COUNT( DISTINCT EMP_ID ) OVER ( PARTITION BY EMP_TYPE ) AS TOTAL_COUNT,
    COUNT( DISTINCT EMP_ID ) OVER ( PARTITION BY EMP_TYPE, DEPT ) AS COUNT_DEPT
FROM
    STAGE_SOURCE
```

**#Edit 2**

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    EMP_TYPE,
    DEPT,
    COUNT( DISTINCT EMP_ID ) OVER ( PARTITION BY EMP_TYPE ) AS TOTAL_COUNT,
    COUNT( DISTINCT EMP_ID ) OVER ( PARTITION BY EMP_TYPE, DEPT ) AS COUNT_DEPT
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT EMP_TYPE, DEPT, EMP_ID FROM STAGE_SOURCE
    ) foo
```

Comment: This was my initial design as i am a great fan of window functions. But in hive, it looks like group by overrides the partition by clause. **Total Count** and **count dept** will have the same count as **count dept**. That is the reason why i had to go with join.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added a second method I'd give a try. Let me know what it brings. Unfortunately, I have no possibility to test it on `Hive`. Though, this approach needs to scan the entire table.

Comment: Just tried the query but got the error `Not yet supported place for UDAF 'COUNT'`

Comment: It is probably due to the fact it can't see `EMP_ID`. Try the query from __#Edit 2__

Comment: Same error again. Looks like hive doesnt support count(distinct) in window function. Do you know anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

by understanding your query, I was able to understand that you need counts of 2 values.
Firstly, Count of EMP_ID's under each EMP_TYPE and,
Secondly. Count of EMP_ID's under DEPT & EMP_TYPE

```
SELECT 

STG.EMP_TYPE, 
DEPT,
TOTAL_COUNT, 
COUNT(EMP_ID) AS COUNT_DEPT

FROM 
STAGE_SOURCE STG 
JOIN 
( SELECT EMP_TYPE, COUNT(EMP_ID) AS TOTAL_COUNT 
  FROM STAGE_SOURCE 
  GROUP BY EMP_TYPE 
) A
ON STG.EMP_TYPE = A.EMP_TYPE
GROUP BY STG.EMP_TYPE, DEPT,TOTAL_COUNT;
```

Using GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT where ever possible can reduce run times.
As mentioned by "Consider Me" above, the GROUP BY takes advantages of Indexes.

Comment: I need the count of total employees which is distinct count of emp_id. There are duplicate entries in the table. So the above query may not give the employee count.